# ggplot2: plotting polygons and points - conflicting scale_color_manual

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have been trying to plot a scatterplot of 35 points, where each of the 7 groups of points (convex hulls) are each demarcated by polygons, with its own manually-defined color (i.e. 7 fill/outline colors). In addition, I am trying to color each of the 35 points with its own specific manually defined color (i.e. 35 colors). I have reproduced the code below, but get the following error: "Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the
existing scale." and clearly unintended results as the points are not colored as desired. Here is my reproducible code:

```
x_val<-c(0.05,0.10,-0.35,-0.20,-0.09,0.43,0.63,0.60, 0.41,0.02,-0.18,0.19,-0.22,0.49,0.20,-0.01,-0.37, -0.48,-0.24,0.21,0.29,-0.18,0.28,-0.22,0.10,0.00,-0.55,0.00,-0.39,-0.43,0.00,0.19,-0.16,0.32,-0.44)
y_val<-c(0.49,-0.40,0.22,0.20,0.03,-0.14,-0.06,0.16,0.20,-0.21,0.42,-0.04,0.13,-0.32,-0.52,0.49,-0.41,-0.13,-0.47,0.33,0.35,0.47,-0.24,0.05,-0.44,0.24,0.20,0.16,-0.22,-0.26,-0.10,-0.04,-0.34,0.13,0.06)
group<-c(4,3,4,6,6,1,1,1,1,3,2,4,6,1,3,6,7,7,5,6,6,6,3,2,3,2,7,6,5,5,6,6,5,6,5)
plot_num<-c(1:35)
my_data<-as.data.frame(cbind(x_val,y_val,group,plot_num),35,4)

plot_col<-c("#83FEA7","#8D1E47","#2BBCB3","#4DB623","#648900","#D460B4","#FF747B","#FAAA94","#D0B5CA","#7D4ED7","#51EEE7","#A079E7","#48A380","#E23195","#A30088","#75FF38","#271CD4","#1061C3","#430B7C","#A6D585","#B7DB50","#50FA64","#B54638","#4890F3","#8D13C0","#78C0FF","#00B584","#77AC2C","#224C41","#1C4278","#77683D","#A1790F","#542E2F","#BDA332","#199338")
group_col<-c("#E67AA1","#5BBFF3","#962786","#6FBBC0","#304552","#7EB440","#1266B4")

find_hull <- function(my_data) my_data[chull(my_data[,1], my_data[,2]), ]
hulls <- ddply(my_data, "group", find_hull)

FF<-ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x_val,y_val, colour=factor(group), fill = factor(group))) +
geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.5) + 
scale_fill_manual(values= group_col) +
scale_color_manual(values= group_col) 

FF +  geom_point(data = my_data, aes(x_val,y_val,colour=factor(plot_num),size=4))+
scale_color_manual(values=plot_col)
```

As you can see, the two scale_color_manual calls conflict, so that neither the outline of the polygons nor the points are colored according to their manually-defined hex codes. FF plots fine on its own, as would the points on their own, such as:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x_val,y_val, colour=factor(plot_num))) +
    geom_point(aes(size=4))+
    scale_color_manual(values=plot_col)
```

But when combined, the plot blows up and an error results. Appreciate your help

Comment: Do you get what you want if you take the colour off the polygon - ie just use `fill`

Comment: Thanks, that works!. While that takes out the polygon borders, its a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use scale_color_manual only once. So I separated the code drawing polygon frame to put "colour = ~~" outside aes().

```
x_val<-c(0.05,0.10,-0.35,-0.20,-0.09,0.43,0.63,0.60, 0.41,0.02,-0.18,0.19,-0.22,0.49,0.20,-0.01,-0.37, -0.48,-0.24,0.21,0.29,-0.18,0.28,-0.22,0.10,0.00,-0.55,0.00,-0.39,-0.43,0.00,0.19,-0.16,0.32,-0.44)
y_val<-c(0.49,-0.40,0.22,0.20,0.03,-0.14,-0.06,0.16,0.20,-0.21,0.42,-0.04,0.13,-0.32,-0.52,0.49,-0.41,-0.13,-0.47,0.33,0.35,0.47,-0.24,0.05,-0.44,0.24,0.20,0.16,-0.22,-0.26,-0.10,-0.04,-0.34,0.13,0.06)
group<-c(4,3,4,6,6,1,1,1,1,3,2,4,6,1,3,6,7,7,5,6,6,6,3,2,3,2,7,6,5,5,6,6,5,6,5)
plot_num<-c(1:35)
my_data<-as.data.frame(cbind(x_val,y_val,group,plot_num),35,4)
plot_col<-c("#83FEA7","#8D1E47","#2BBCB3","#4DB623","#648900","#D460B4","#FF747B","#FAAA94","#D0B5CA","#7D4ED7","#51EEE7","#A079E7","#48A380","#E23195","#A30088","#75FF38","#271CD4","#1061C3","#430B7C","#A6D585","#B7DB50","#50FA64","#B54638","#4890F3","#8D13C0","#78C0FF","#00B584","#77AC2C","#224C41","#1C4278","#77683D","#A1790F","#542E2F","#BDA332","#199338")
group_col<-c("#E67AA1","#5BBFF3","#962786","#6FBBC0","#304552","#7EB440","#1266B4")
find_hull <- function(my_data) my_data[chull(my_data[,1], my_data[,2]), ]
hulls <- ddply(my_data, "group", find_hull)


# make a color vector from group column
g.col <- group_col[hulls$group]

FF <- ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x_val,y_val)) +  
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.5, aes(fill=factor(group))) +  # fill
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0, aes(group=factor(group)), colour=g.col) + # draw lines with specific color
  scale_fill_manual(values= group_col)  # change fill color.

## If you needn't legend, you'll use integrated code.
# geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.5, aes(group=factor(group)), fill=g.col, colour=g.col)

FF +  geom_point(data = my_data, aes(x_val, y_val, colour=factor(plot_num)), size=4) +
  scale_color_manual(values=plot_col)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks! Great solution, and very helpful for understanding the quirks of color commands in ggplot.